# Odoo- How load products with multiple parents

Tags: orm, odoo, relation, odoo-10

I am working on Odoo 10e . I have situation which i am unable to solve in here.

I have a relation like following

```
Customer 1-------* Shipments 1-------* Shipment Detail 1-----* Products
```

Now i have a separate form in which i want to show products which are associated against a specific Customer in dropdown . How can i do this in Odoo

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to sort all products that have related to the Customer who selected in form view?

You can do this way:

```py
@api.depends('customer')
def get_related_product(self):
   res = []
   #compute to get your product id here 
   return res

customer = fields.Many2one(....)
related_product = fields.Many2many(......., compute='get_related_product')
```